# React-Konva Custom Shape using arcTo renders incorrectly

Tags: konvajs, konvajs-reactjs

I am using [Konva](https://konvajs.org/) with [Konva-React](https://konvajs.org/docs/react/) to draw a simple custom shape consisting of two perpendicular lines joined by an arc.

[image: Simple Custom Shape]

The API documentation for [custom shape](https://konvajs.org/docs/react/Custom_Shape.html) states that we can use the renderer to access the HTML5 Canvas context. As such I have created a drawing function that uses the Konva.Canvas renderer to display my shape, however the shape does not render as expected. See: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-custom-shape-demo-hs3y4.

[image]

This renders correctly when using HTML5 Canvas https://codepen.io/anon/pen/voYNLR.

After several permutations (using typescript) I managed to generate an error message that highlights an issue with the arcTo command:

```
 Expected 6 arguments, but got 5.  TS2554
```

However https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/ specifically states that arcTo has 5 parameters:

```
context.arcTo(x1, y1, x2, y2, radius)
```

On further investigation Context.d.ts states:

```
         arc(a0: any, a1: any, a2: any, a3: any, a4: any, a5: any): void;   
         arcTo(a0: any, a1: any, a2: any, a3: any, a4: any, a5: any): void; <== Note 6 args (the same as arc)
```

The definition of arcTo in nodemodules\konva\lib\Context.js has what I believe to be a bug:

```
function Context(canvas) {
this.canvas = canvas;
this._context = canvas._canvas.getContext('2d');
……
Context.prototype.arc = function (a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5) {
this._context.arc(a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5);
};
Context.prototype.arcTo = function (a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5) {
this._context.arc(a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5);
};
```

Notice here that the implementation of the prototype for arcTo uses _context.arc in place of arcTo. I would appreciate any validation of these findings, or some background if this is intended behaviour.

I have created a fork with a modified arcTo signature here: https://github.com/piriej/konva (warning: work in progress)

Kind Regards
Jeff

Comment: Can you create an issue on github with the bug? Or even make a pull request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a bug in wrapping of context methods inside `Konva` codebase.
As workaround you can call `arcTo` directly:

```
 context._context.arcTo(150, 20, 150, 70, 50);
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-custom-shape-demo-4u6kz